# Could anyone tell me why my function works in index.php but not in functions.php?

Tags: php

I'm new to stackoverflow and PHP so please bare with me :) I'm having a problem with displaying correct information on my WordPress site and I'm not sure why. I have written this function that is in functions.php:

```
function my_page_id(){  
  $page_id = get_queried_object_id();
  echo "Page ID = " . esc_html($page_id);
}
add_action('init', 'my_page_id');
```

This displays

```
"Page ID = 0"
```

However, when I call the function directly in one of my other files such as index.php:

```
my_page_id();
```

It displays:

```
"Page ID = (correct ID number)"
```

Could anyone tell me why??

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: Are you using wordpress?

Comment: Yes, I should have stated that!

Comment: You can edit the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `currently_queried_object` is the object that is subject of the webpage.

So on a category archive or tag archive page it will return the `WP_Term` object of that page.
On any singular page (a single post, a single page, or a post in a custom post type), it will return the `WP_Post` object of that post or page.

So, if you use the function in your `functions.php` there is no `currently_queried_object` and therefore the `id` is `0`

Comment: Thanks, can I request that information on functions.php??

Comment: Why would you need the `currently_queried_object_id` in `function.php`?

Comment: I wanted to write a function that would tell me what the page ID was. Like I said, I'm new to PHP so maybe this isn't best practice??

Comment: I understand, and you wrote that function, except it will never return anything other then 0 if you call it in `functions.php` since that file is technically not a page. If you call it in `index.php` as you said, it will return something and that is how you should use it.

Comment: Sure thing! @MattElks

Comment: Could you mark my answer as correct then @MattElks

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks again for your help :)